# Python - Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas

I use python to insert column for two txt file "amazon" and "yelp"
By the function below, it works properly.
Here is the code:

```
for i in range(len(amazon)+1):
    a[i]='amazon'
amazon.insert(2,'label',a[i])

for i in range(len(yelp)+1):
    a[i]='yelp'
yelp.insert(2,'label',a[i])
```

However, while I use  a user define function to call it, there are some errors happend. May I know is there any wrong with the function since I use the same logic above

```
def label(doc):
    for i in range(len(doc)):
        a[i]=doc
    return doc.insert(2,'label',a[i])

------------error msg:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-493-cc2a2cf79348> in <module>()
----> 1 label(imdb)

<ipython-input-492-d9cdd4df272b> in label(doc)
      2     for i in range(len(doc)):
      3         a[i]=doc
----> 4     return doc.insert(2,'label',a[i])

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   2421         value = self._sanitize_column(column, value, broadcast=False)
   2422         self._data.insert(loc, column, value,
-> 2423                           allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
   2424 
   2425     def assign(self, **kwargs):

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   3817 
   3818         block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim,
-> 3819                            placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
   3820 
   3821         for blkno, count in _fast_count_smallints(self._blknos[loc:]):

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)
   2717                      placement=placement, dtype=dtype)
   2718 
-> 2719     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
   2720 
   2721 # TODO: flexible with index=None and/or items=None

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in __init__(self, values, ndim, fastpath, placement, **kwargs)
   1842 
   1843         super(ObjectBlock, self).__init__(values, ndim=ndim, fastpath=fastpath,
-> 1844                                           placement=placement, **kwargs)
   1845 
   1846     @property

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim, fastpath)
    113             raise ValueError('Wrong number of items passed %d, placement '
    114                              'implies %d' % (len(self.values),
--> 115                                              len(self.mgr_locs)))
    116 
    117     @property

**ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1**
```

Comment: I check the API, the insert function can have three arguments : insert(index_location,column_name,value)  is that correct?

Comment: I think you meant to do `a[i]=doc[i]`.

Comment: And when I use just for loop to insert the column it works while I use the define function, it has value.

Comment: yes exactly and a[i] is a new column I want to add